# Enforce QWidget aspect ratio using sizeIncrement

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qwidget, qt-designer, qlayout

I am designing a form in Qt Creator Designer. I want to make a QWidget that will always keep 4:3 aspect ratio and will keep the remaining space around itself empty.

I put it in a grid layout and surounded it with spacers which I thought would consume any extra space:

[image: image description]

After that, I set it's minimum size to 48x32 and it's size increment to 2x3:

[image: image description]

I tried all size policies but it never respects the aspect ratio. It also doesn't properly try to fit the whole area.

How do I set it up correctly?

Comment: Does the answer to this *have* to be QML based?  Or will a C++ answer suffice?

Comment: There are already C++ based answers on this topic and they do not work. A did manage to get this to - somewhat - work by heavy C++ meddling although it\s far from ideal.

Comment: Are you working under Windows env? From the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizeIncrement-prop) : _Warning: The size increment has no effect under Windows, and may be disregarded by the window manager on X11._